# How to find asymptotic behaviour of this differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, asymptotics

Please, somebody could help me How to find asymptotic behaviour of this differential equation?

$$  \xi \frac{d^{2}R}{d\xi ^{2}} + \frac{dR}{d\xi}-\left (\frac{m^{2}}{4\xi}+\xi+\beta \right )R(\xi)=0  \qquad , \qquad m,\beta  \in \mathbb{Z}^{+} $$

I need to find solutions when $\xi \to 0$  and when $\xi \to \infty$.
I found solutions ($R\sim e^{\frac{|m|}{2}}$
and $R\sim e^{-\xi}$, respectively) at webpages, but I can't understand the analysis performed.

(Any book that can explain this situation is also welcome.)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You'll have $R \sim C_1 \xi^{r_1} + C_2 \xi^{r_2}$ at zero, where $r_{1, 2}$ are the roots of the indicial equation, and $R \sim C_1 e^{\alpha_1 \xi} \xi^{s_1} + C_2 e^{\alpha_2 \xi} \xi^{s_2}$ at infinity, where $\alpha_{1, 2}$ and $s_{1, 2}$ can be found by substituting $R = e^{\alpha \xi} \xi^s$ into the ODE and eliminating the two dominant terms. A good book is Bender, Orszag, *Advanced Mathematical Methods for Scientists and Engineers*.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Maxim! 
I still have doubts about the criteria taken into account for not considering the first two terms of the ODE : $\xi \frac{d^{2}}{d\xi ^{2}},\frac{d}{d \xi}$.
I will review the book.